# Plot histogram on binary based column data versus continuous column of data

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Here is the data showing two columns between which I need to plot histogram

```
Cont    Bin_Data
    21      1
    21      1
    22.8    1
    21.4    0
    18.7    0
    18.1    0
    14.3    0
    24.4    0
    22.8    1
    19.2    1
    17.8    0
    16.4    1
    17.3    0
    15.2    1
```

I have to plot Bin_Data(column) based histogram to compare Cont(column). I have tried 3 approaches and am not getting satisfactory result/plot.

**Approach #1**

```
   plt.hist('mpg', bins=5, data=am)
```

**Approach #2**

```
 plt.hist(mpg, bins=np.arange(mpg.min(), mpg.max()+1))
```

**Approach #3**

```
    am = data['am']
    legend = ['am', 'mpg']
    mpg = data['mpg']
    plt.hist([mpg, am], color=['orange', 'green'])
    plt.xlabel("am")
    plt.ylabel("mpg")
    plt.legend(legend)
    #plt.xticks(range(0, 7))
    #plt.yticks(range(1, 20))
    plt.title('Analysis of "am" upon "mpg"')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: What causes your insatisfaction?

Comment: All three approaches shows plot where the binary data gets plotted on the x or y axis but the plot is not showing 0 or 1 rather it shows values till 10,20 or 30. I believe it should be something I can relate to  binary versus continuous.